# Custom Postgres function for term dates and times

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets say I have a large table that just consists of three columns.

Integer id,
timestamp ts,
double value

If I wanted to get the values given a complicated date expression what is the best way to achieve that ?

For example if I wanted to get all the values at anytime on weekend days and only between 18:00 and 8:00 on weekdays and any time on school holidays for the year 2014.

Obviously some of these times are variable and so the solution should be dynamic. I was thinking 
of storing a series of date intervals for things like school holidays in another table to check against. However, I would like to create a custom Postgres function to hide some of the complexity.

Does anyone know of similar code or have suggestions ?
Especially dealing with cases like the times above except on weekend logic ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a holiday table

```
select *
from
    t
    left join
    holiday on date_trunc('day', t.ts) = holiday.day
where
    extract(dow from ts) in (0, 6) -- Weekend
    or
    (extract(hour from ts) >= 18 and extract(hour from ts) <= 8)
    or
    holiday.day is not null -- Holiday
```